# Using the global variable POST in PHP to receive a java script variable

Tags: php, javascript, post, canvas

Im a high school student and im trying to finish up my final project for my webdesign class. Ive run into a problem with the global array "POST" in PHP.

Some background info: I have a HTML 5 canvas element that I have used Js (JavaScript) on to be able to draw on the canvas. So far everything is fine. Now I want to save the canvas to a text file on the server so someone else is able to fetch this .txt file and repaint the canvas.

On to the actual problem. I have used the function ".toDataUrl()" to extract a code for the canvas. Now i want to send this using AJAX to a php file which in turn writes it into a txt file, then it should close the file and exit the php script.

Currently my code looks like this:

Javascript:

```
function save() {
    if (selectSave.selectedIndex == 0) {
        dataURLSave1 = canvas.toDataURL();
        var request = ajaxRequest;
        request.open("POST", "http://berzanlabb.se/te11e/jimbjo310/Projektsida/write_1.php", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", dataURLSave1.length);
        request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            alert("Done: "+request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send(dataURLSave1);

    return;
}
```

and php:

```php
<?php
$file=fopen("save_1.txt","w+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$_POST['dataURLSave1']; 
$test=$_POST['dataURLSave1'];
echo fwrite($file,"$test");
fclose($file);
?>
```

This code works with the global variable "GET" but not with POST. The problem im facing is that GET is not long enough to send the variable I want to send. So I have goen for POST instead. But right now im not sure why the php arent getting the variable.

Im sorry if the formatting is the wrost youve ever seen or if this question has bee nasked before. Ive tried to search around the net for an answer but I have yet to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this explains exatly what you want: [HTML5: Saving Canvas Image Data Using PHP And Ajax](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/).

Comment: I have literary no clue why that worked, but thank you. My problem was in the PHP part of the function. I have no prior pexperience of PHP so thank you for the help.